# how to retrieve twitter, linkedIn profile data espacially Email in asp.net mvc 4 using Oauth

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, twitter-oauth

i am new in OAuth. I want to retrieve twitter, LinkedIn profile data especially Email, but i couldn't find any helpful post.

```
AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
```

**ExtraData** field contains:

**Facebook:** username (Email address), name, link (URL to their facebook page), gender, birthday

**Twitter:** name, location, description, url (URL to Twitter page)

**LinkedIn:** name, headline, summary, industry

as mention only Facebook provide email, but both Twitter and LinkedIn are not, how to retrieve email id.

Comment: For twitter look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599621/is-there-a-way-to-get-an-users-email-id-after-verifying-her-twitter-identity-us

For linkedin look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860359/retrieve-linkedin-email-address

Comment: @Garath twitter user's email address can not be retrieved via the API. while now i am able to get email address from linkedIn profile

Comment: About twitter exactly this was written in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599621/is-there-a-way-to-get-an-users-email-id-after-verifying-her-twitter-identity-us

Comment: so we should wait for the email address from twitter :(

Comment: What for you need this information?