# c# - Cannot implicitly convert type 'oAuthCredentials' to 'string'

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to get comments from linkedin by using API

But I'm getting an error, in few places

Can anyone help me to resolve an error?

I've written this code

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var request = new RestRequest { Path = "posts?order=recency&category=discussion" };

        var credentials = new OAuthCredentials

        {
            ConsumerKey = "kmkzt9cqml1s", 
            ConsumerSecret = "hNiwIrZWGSMykoD2", 
        };


        var client = new RestClient()
        {
            Authority = "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/groups/345455/",
            Credentials = credentials//Here I'm getting an error
        };

        //Here how to create Request method
        var MyInfo = client.Request(request);

        String content = MyInfo.Content;

        string strURL = "http://api.linkedin.com/";
        System.Net.HttpWebRequest objWebRequest = null;
        System.Net.HttpWebResponse objWebResponse = null;
        System.IO.StreamReader streamReader = null;
        string strHTML = null;

        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(object s, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };

        objWebRequest = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(strURL);
        objWebRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
        objWebRequest.Method = "GET";

        objWebRequest.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        objWebResponse = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)objWebRequest.GetResponse();

        streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(objWebResponse.GetResponseStream());

        strHTML = streamReader.ReadToEnd();


        streamReader.Close();
        objWebResponse.Close();
        objWebRequest.Abort();

        Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
        Response.Write(strHTML);
        Response.End();

    }
```

RestClient.cs

```
 public class RestClient
  {
    private string _consumerKey = "";
    private string _consumerSecret = "";

    #region Properties
    public string Authority
    {
        get
        {
            return _consumerKey;
        }
        set { _consumerKey = value; }
    }

    //Here giving string
    public string Credentials
    {
        get
        {
            return _consumerSecret;
        }
        set { _consumerSecret = value; }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

How to create Request() Method?
Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Exception in topic caused by invalid implicit cast. Check line which compiler point you and resolve issue. Code you provided is too common.

Comment: Double click the error and you wil land in the line where the error is caused. Hover over the left and right side of the assignment to see that you are using incompatible datatypes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, you're trying to assign a `OAuthCredentials` object (credentials) into a string typed attribute of the `RestClient` object : `Credentials`.

You have to either do `Credentials = credentials.toString()` or change the `RestClient` class.

Comment: It's working Thanks, and one more thing how to create Request() method

Comment: I couldn't know, since I don't have a clue what it is supposed to do :)

Comment: Go through this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860359/retrieve-linkedin-email-address

Answer (score 0):

Your `RestClient` has a `Credentials` property that is a string; Your code is trying to put something that isn't a string (in your case, an `OAuthCredentials`) into it. This is not a allowable, as there is no implicit conversion between the two types.

Answer (score 0):

In `RestClient`, `Credentials` is string, but you are affecting a `OAuthCredentials` to it ( `Credentials = credentials` ).

Try changing the type of the property (and the backing field) `Credentials` to `OAuthCredentials`.

Answer (score 0):

`Credentials` is not of type `OAuthCredentials`, it's of type `string`, so you can't assign it with your `credentials` variable, which is of type `OAuthCredentials`. Since the `RestClient` class references a variable named `_consumerSecret`, and such and so, let's assume you actually want to do this:

```
Authority = credentials.ConsumerKey;
Credentials = credentials.ConsumerSecret;
```